# Plone: Pass a variable from PloneFormGen Custom Script Adapter to Mailer Adapter

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I have a PloneFormGen form with a Custom Script Adapter that, on form submission, generates a new uid and creates a folder with that uid as its ID.

```
from DateTime import DateTime
uid = str(DateTime().millis())
target.invokeFactory("Folder", id=uid, title=form['your-name'])
```

It uses input from the form to create various items in that folder, including a document called "newpage", which I then want to include a link to in an email. Is there a way to pass the uid variable from the script adapter to the mailer adapter, so that I can generate the link to the new documents inside the folder?

For instance, the script adapter creates a folder with the ID 1317142676351, so when the form is submitted, the URL for one of the new pages is http://mysite.com/submissions/1317142676351/newpage/. I want to be able to include that link in one of my Mailer Adapter templates, but I don't know how to get the uid that was generated in the Custom Script Adapter, or if that's even possible. What happens first, the Mailer, or the Custom Script Adapter?

Any push in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a case where -- since you are adding content -- that content rules (trigger on add, execute a mailing action) could take care of the mailing use-case you have, instead of relying on a script running in the PloneFormGen context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy the id value to the request. In the script, code like:

```
request.set('custom_id', id)
```

will do it. If you need the variable to be automatically handled, create a matching hidden variable in the form.

Comment: Thanks for that tip! I created a hidden string variable in the form with the default value "python: str(DateTime().millis())" and it worked like a charm!

Comment: You can create the hidden field in the form, but you'll want to set the id value in your script. Otherwise, you'll be creating an opportunity for a hacker to override the value.